# Private_pub with SSL on AWS

Tags: https, amazon-web-services, thin, faye, private-pub

I'm trying to run a separate secure pub/sub thin server using private_pub (which uses faye) and the instructions for serving over SSL: https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub#serving-faye-over-https-with-thin

My app is fairly barebones with just the config and initializer files as created by private_pub. It works fine when I run it on localhost, but I want to host it on an AWS instance that has an elastic IP that my domain redirects to (the SSL certificate is for the domain).

However, when I run the thin server on AWS and open the HTTPS link for the server on port 4443, it keeps trying to load the page and times out. I don't think it's an issue with the certificates since it seems to be working fine on localhost, so I couldn't trace the problem. Is there something I need to setup on AWS so that the thin server there can respond to HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this - it was a minor thing that I missed: all I needed to do was add a security group rule for my instance for the SSL port